# Can someone break my zip files passwords?

Tags: security, zip, password-protection, unzip

I have made a system that reads password protected zip files. Only my source code knows the password to unzip the file. But my question is:

Is there any way that a person very interested in knowing what I am hiding in that zip file be able to discover my 32 bytes password?

I found this on the Internet: http://archiveflasher.blogspot.com.br/

I did not tested it yet because we have to accept merchandising in order to complete download.

---

**Included after:**

If 7Zip is the best way to secure zip files, Will zip4j be able to open files with those kind of encryption? Also: Does Delphi has a free library for 7zip with this password support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 bit encryption is very vulnerable to brute force attacks. You may want to look into higher-grade encryption if the contents of your zip file are very sensitive. [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is free and can encrypt zip files in 256-bit AES.

Comment: If 7Zip is the best way to secure zip files, Will zip4j be able to open files with those kind of encryption? Also: Does Delphi has a free library for 7zip with this password support?

Comment: Zip4j supports 256-bit AES encryption as long as it is winzip. 7-zip uses the winzip standard, so I think it should work.

Comment: isnt 32bytes and 256bit equivalent?